# Passing JSON result into a struct model

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode, struct

I am receiving a result from an API, I can iterate through the result. My understanding is I can pass the value into a model immediately.

[Apple Developer article on struct models](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=37)

My issue is I am not doing it properly and am receiving a nil value. Perhaps someone can see where I need to change.  I am using Swift 4.2

Here is my struct model.

```
import Foundation

struct ProfileModel {

//MARK: Properties

var name: String
var email: String
var profileURL: String

//MARK: Initialization


}
extension ProfileModel{
  init?(json: [String:AnyObject]) {
    guard
        let name = json["name"] as? String,
        let email = json["email"] as? String,
        let profileURL = json["profileURL"] as? String
        else { return nil }

    self.name = name
    self.email = email
    self.profileURL = profileURL
  }
}
```

Here is my result code from my urlConnection. Let me know if we want to see the entire swift file

```
//create dataTask using the session object to send data to the server
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { data, response, error in

        guard error == nil else {
            return
        }

        guard let data = data else {
            return
        }

        do {
            //create json object from data
            if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String:AnyObject] {

                self.onSuccess(data: json)

            }
        } catch let error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    })
    task.resume()

}


func onSuccess(data: [String:AnyObject]){
  print("onSuccess")

  let myProfile = ProfileModel(json: data)
  //myProfile is nil while unwrapping
  let title: String = myProfile!.name
  print(title)
}
```

---

I could just iterate through the strings since I am able to print 'data'. I just figured it would be cleaner to put everything into a ProfileModel and manage that object as a whole.

This json is my more simple one which is why I used it for this question. I also can't remember but I had to use "[String:AnyObject]" to get the json properly. This was pulled directly from my terminal, this was the data being passed in my JsonResponse. The output json from Xcode has [] on the outside instead.

```
{
'detail': 'VALID', 
‘name’: ‘Carson, 
'email': ‘carson.skjerdal@somethingelselabs.com', 
'pic_url': None
}
```

---

EDIT:

So my problem is solved, and ultimately moving to Codable was the key. Here is my fixed code for anyone who might need a working solution.

```
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { (data, response
        , error) in
        guard let data = data else { return }
        do {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            let gitData = try decoder.decode(ProfileModel.self, from: data)
            print(gitData.name)
            self.onSuccess(data: gitData)

        } catch let err {
            print("Err", err)
        }
        }.resume()

}

func onSuccess(data: ProfileModel){
  print("onSuccess")

  print(data.email)

}
```

My Codable Struct - slightly simplified

```
import Foundation
```

struct ProfileModel: Codable {
    let detail, name, email: String

```
private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case detail, email
    case name = "firstname"
    //case picUrl = "pic_url"
}
```

}

Comment: Your init is failable. Well it’s failing.

Comment: Rather than *to see the entire swift file* it would be more helpful to see the JSON. And the mentioned Apple article does not suggest `AnyObject` nor `mutableContainers`. By the way the article is outdated anyway in favor of the `Codable` protocol

Comment: `init?(json:)`: Failable. There is inside a `guard condition1, condition2, condition 3 else { return nil }`. Might want to check which one of the condition is failing, and why.

Comment: Added my json, does my init fail if even one fail? I fixed a spelling error just now so I'll run that. Edit:I fixed all my spelling to line up so it should be fine.  @vadin I didn't realize it was outdated, I figured this was most up to date.

Comment: This is not valid JSON. All strings but be wrapped in double quotes e.g. `"detail": "VALID"`. And the JSON doesn't match your model, there is no `profileURL` key, in this case the initializer fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After "Codable" has been introduced I always uses that.
You can take your JSON ans pars it in to QuickType.io, and you will get a Struct that confirms to the codadable

```
// To parse the JSON, add this file to your project and do:
//
//   let aPIResponse = try? newJSONDecoder().decode(APIResponse.self, from: jsonData)

import Foundation

struct APIResponse: Codable {
    let detail, name, email, picUrl: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case detail, name, email
        case picUrl = "pic_url"
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, I won't vote this correct (yet) but that is a huge step for me. Sounds like Codable is the way to go for this though.

Comment: I marked this correct since it was a big step, I'll post my correct code for anyone who reads my post.